# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response With Parse error code 100

Tags: java, parse-platform

Am using Parse DB for my backend , used method like Login,SaveInBackground,FindInBackGround, most of the function is working except, One function which uses  SaveInBackground(){....} other method with same SaveInBackground () is working

This is the method for which the error occurred

```
 private void xxdatat(final ParseObject receiverObject) {
    ParseObject obj = new ParseObject(Constants.XXX);
    obj.put("SENDER_ID", objdata);          //parse object type
    obj.put("RECIEIVER_ID", Robjdata);      //parse object type
    obj.put("REQUEST_TYPE", stingdata);     //String type
    obj.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e==null) {
                DialogUtil.showDialog(mContext, "working");
            } else {
                DialogUtil.showDialog(mContext,"Not working");

            }
        }
    });
```

I surfed through the internet and find some solutions to be made in parse configuration file.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(APP_ID)
            .clientKey(CLIENT_KEY)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new ParseLogInterceptor())
            .server("https://parse.xxxyyyzzz.com/parse/")
            .build());
```

The link is completed by "/"

As observed there are errors while converting the data from parse to JSONObject and the exception is also JSONException.

How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
    at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:290)
    at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:308)
    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
    at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
    at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
    at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
    at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
    at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
    at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:298)
    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137) 
    at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133) 
    at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917) 
    at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105) 
    at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908) 
    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715) 
    at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726) 
    at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818) 
    at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806) 
    at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: That means your JSON is not valid format.

Comment: check your json url is valid or not? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Actually converting JSON will be done by the parse SDK , There is no my part of code goes in.And It works initially well. after few days i doesn't.

Comment: What version of the sdk are you using?

Comment: parse sdk version 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this issues by creating a new table in db with same structure and different name.

Now there is no issues working fine.